# Renaming columns in list of data frames using match from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rename, lapply

I realise I asked two separate questions in my last post and had one of them answered by very clever peeps super quickly.

Obviously I still can't wrap my head around data frame lists or lapply!

I have csv list of original questions and renamed questions. In this example, I am trying to write the code to update Q.1a to Q.1 as per the Qs data frame.

```
df1 <- data.frame("ID" = 1, "Q.1" = 2, Q1.1 = 3)
df2 <- data.frame("ID." = 2, "Q.1a" = 3, Q1.1 = 4)


dflist <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame") get(x))
dflist <- Filter(length, dflist)


Qs  <- data.frame("Original.Name" = "Q.1a", "New.Name" = "Q.1")
```

The tables look like this: I want to update Q.1a as per the Qs table

```
  ID Q.1a Q1.1
1  1    2    3

  ID. Q.1 Q1.1
1   2   3    4

  Original.Name New.name
1           Q.1a      Q.1
```

The code I am trying to write to rename the questions that is currently full of errors, I am sure the piping is not supposed to be there!

```
lapply(dflist, function(x) {
  names(x) <- names (x) %in%
  Qs$Original.name = Qs$New.name[match(names(x)[names(x) %in% Qs$Original.name],
         Qs$Original.name)]
})
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks so much.

Edited to show expected output where Q1a from the original example above has been upated to Q1.

```
  ID Q.1 Q1.1
1  1   2    3
  ID. Q.1 Q1.1
1   2   3    4
```

Ideally I want to be able to match and replace the column names from the Qs table. The original column name replaced with new column name

Comment: What is your expected output? `dflist` has column names `ID Q1 Q11` and `ID Q1a Q11` what should it change to?

Comment: Ah thanks for the question. The real data is wide and has lots of columns. The CSV has the original column names and the new column names. This table is Qs. In this example the original question Q1a in the df needs to be Q1.

Comment: So what I want to do is write a match function across all the data frames that matches the new column name to the old one and updates all data frames

Comment: I've edited to be clearer about expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ifelse` with `match` to get new names of the columns.

```
dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {
   names(x) <- ifelse(names(x) %in% Qs$Original.Name, 
                      Qs$New.Name[match(names(x), Qs$Original.Name)], names(x))
   x
})

dflist
#[[1]]
#  ID Q.1 Q1.1
#1  1   2    3

#[[2]]
#  ID. Q.1 Q1.1
#1   2   3    4
```

Comment: depending on your `default.stringsAsFactors()` settings, you may have to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating the `Qs` data.frame to make it work

Comment: > df1 <- data.frame("ID" = 1, "Q.1a" = 2, Q1.1 = 3)
> df2 <- data.frame("ID." = 2, "Q.1" = 3, Q1.1 = 4)
> 
> 
> dflist <- lapply(ls(), function(x) if (class(get(x)) == "data.frame") get(x))
> dflist <- Filter(length, dflist)
> 
> 
> 
> Qs <- data.frame("Original.Name" = "Q.1a", "New.Name" = "Q.1")
> 
> dflist <- lapply(dflist, function(x) {
+   names(x) <- ifelse(names(x) %in% Qs$Original.Name, 
+                      Qs$New.Name[match(names(x), Qs$Original.Name)], names(x))
+   x
+ })
> 
> dflist
[[1]]
  ID 1 Q1.1
1  1 2    3

[[2]]
  ID. Q.1 Q1.1
1   2   3    4

Comment: Wierdly I get 1 instead of Q.1. I am sure I copied it right!

Comment: Yes, that's what @starja is talking about. Use `Qs  <- data.frame("Original.Name" = "Q.1a", "New.Name" = "Q.1", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Yay thanks so much I tried that but I should have cleared the environment and run it all againg.